# Pass POST over to two pages?

Tags: php, html, post

I have the following pages (code fragments only)

**Form.html**

```
<form method="post" action="post.php">
<input type="text" name="text" placeholder="enter your custom text />
<input type="submit">
</form
```

**post.php**

```
....
some code here
....
header('Location: process.php');
```

**process.php**

on this page, the "text" input from form.html is needed.

My problem is now, how do i pass the input-post from the first page through process.php without loosing it?

i dont want to use a  `process.php?var=text_variable` because my input can be a large html text, formated by the CKeditor plugin (a word-like text editor) and would result in something like this `process.php?var=<html><table><td>customtext</td>......`

How can i get this problem solved?

I would like to have a pure php solution and avoid js,jquery if that is possible.

Comment: Add the variables to the `$_SESSION` array and you can use them anywhere you start the session.

Comment: a header redirect doesn't offer a way to post data. You should store the post data from the first page in session and then pull from session on subsequent pages.

Comment: If you've split this up into `post` and then `process`, then why aren't you saving to a db in post.php? Its strange to me that so many beginners try to do everything without a db when everything is easier with one and every hosting company out there gives you one in the bundle.

Comment: Or session rather than db. It depends on what you're really doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use $_SESSION you can also make a form in the page and then send the data to the next page

```
<form method="POST" id="toprocess" action="process.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="text" value="<?php echo $_POST["text"]; ?>" />
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById("toprocess").submit();
</script>
```

or you can the submit the form part to whatever results in moving to another page.

Having said that using the $_SESSION is the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Either use `$_SESSION` or include process.php with a predefined var calling the post.

```
$var = $_POST['postvar'];
include process.php;
```

Process.php has `echo $var;` or you can write a function into process.php to which you can pass `var`.

Comment: Rewrite process.php to work by function and call the function you need and pass the var.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the doc can help: http://php.net/manual/fr/httprequest.send.php

especially example #2:

```
$r = new HttpRequest('http://example.com/form.php', HttpRequest::METH_POST);
$r->setOptions(array('cookies' => array('lang' => 'de')));
$r->addPostFields(array('user' => 'mike', 'pass' => 's3c|r3t'));
$r->addPostFile('image', 'profile.jpg', 'image/jpeg');
try {
    echo $r->send()->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
```

But I wouldn't use this heavy way where sessions are possible and much easier, see previous answer/comments.
This is ok for instance if you want to call a pre-existing script awaiting post-data, if you can't (or don't want to) modify the called script. Or if there's no possible session (cross-domain call for instance).

Comment: I don't really like the idea of sending a http request to the same server. It's like calling sending a post card to your own home.

Comment: @Mouser I totally agree, that's why I precised it's usefull for crossdom or, sometimes, to call scripts you can't/don't want to modify. Ex. you want a login-page of your own to call your own script to take some actions, then connect to a CMS / you don't want to touch the CMS in order not to have issues when updating it... In such a case, posting to the original CMS-login-processing script might be an easy turnaround.

Comment: The latter still seems unnecessary. I can catch the drift, but you could write a page in between to handle the calls and not change your CMS.

Comment: @Mouser "in between ... handle the calls"? Could you be more precise, I don't get it. Icould be interested in a better solutions than a workaround.

Comment: Well I have a CMS running that I scripted myself. File handles are routed in a php file. That file is written in a way that it contains functions so it can be included to any script. When called upon it won't make any changes to the CMS, except when I call upon a function. Those function can be called upon by the original script. In your case a login script.

Comment: This is just too contrived for this simple of a problem. The right answer is simply "use a db."

Comment: I agree it's too contrived in most cases, but I faced some situations (well one, actually) where it really helped. I don't agree with DB, it's much too contrived too just to pass a value from a page to another, this is exactly the role of session variables.